# Issue: Porting Docker to a new platform (Tizen 4.0 + ARM64)

Tags: docker, porting, tizen

I have been trying to port Docker CE on a new platform (Tizen 4.0 + ARM64) using static binaries as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/)

However, even though I meet all the pre-requisites described in above link, I keep getting this error while trying to run docker daemon :

`WARN[2018-10-04T14:14:57.890120101+09:00] Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: WARNING: Module bridge not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.59-g70b545c-dirty modprobe: WARNING: Module br_netfilter not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.59-g70b545c-dirty, error: exit status 1`

`WARN[2018-10-04T14:14:57.905153370+09:00] Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: modprobe: WARNING: Module nf_nat not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.59-g70b545c-dirty, error: exit status 1`

`WARN[2018-10-04T14:14:57.920222485+09:00] Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: modprobe: WARNING: Module xt_conntrack not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.59-g70b545c-dirty, error: exit status 1`

**`Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: package not installed`**

Is there anyway to fix this? 

**Otherwise, Is there some alternative way to port docker onto a new platform (In this case: Tizen 4.0 + ARM64).** 

 Key note: The platform uses a linux kernel but doesn't support many typical Linux Platform features like apt-get commands.
 

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker, by itself, requires a lot of pre-requesites to run on a new platform. Some of them are mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/#install-daemon-and-client-binaries-on-linux).

Apart from meeting the pre-requisites, one has to meet specific kernel requirements and in case, the kernel doesn't meet all those requirements, one has to patch the kernel accordingly to get the things running.

Here are the kernel defconfigs, one must enable to get docker running  -

CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y, CONFIG_CPUSETS=y, CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y, CONFIG_CGROUPS=y, CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT=y, CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y, CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER=y, CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED=y, - CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF=y, CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB=y, CONFIG_NET_CLS_CGROUP=y,  CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_PRIO=y, CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH=y, CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS=y, CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y, CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ADDRTYPE=y, CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=y, CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS=y, CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV4=y, CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y, CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE=y, CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT=y, CONFIG_NF_NAT=y, CONFIG_NF_NAT_NEEDED=y, CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE=y, CONFIG_MEMCG=y, CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP=y, CONFIG_MEMCG_KMEM=y, CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLED=y, CONFIG_BRIDGE=y, CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER=y, CONFIG_VXLAN=y, CONFIG_CRYPTO=y, CONFIG_CRYPTO_AEAD=y, CONFIG_CRYPTO_GCM=y, CONFIG_CRYPTO_SEQIV=y, CONFIG_CRYPTO_GHASH=y, CONFIG_XFRM=y, CONFIG_XFRM_USER=y, CONFIG_XFRM_ALGO=y, CONFIG_INET_ESP=y, CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT=y, CONFIG_IPVLAN=y, CONFIG_MACVLAN=y, CONFIG_DUMMY=y, ": CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP=y, CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP=y, CONFIG_NF_NAT_TFTP=y, CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP=y, CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS=y, CONG_AUFS_FS=y, CONFIG_BTRFS_FS=y, CONFIG_BTRFS_FS_POSIX_ACL=y, CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM=y, CONFIG_DM_THIN_PROVISIONING=y, CONFIG_NAMESPACES=y, CONFIG_NET_NS=y, CONFIG_PID_NS=y, CONFIG_IPC_NS=y, CONFIG_UTS_NS=y, CONFIG_KEYS=y, CONFIG_VETH=y, CONFIG_USER_NS=y, CONFIG_SECCOMP=y, CONFIG_BLK_DEV_THROTTLING=y, CONFIG_IOSCHED_CFQ=y, CONFIG_CFQ_GROUP_IOSCHED=y, CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED=y, CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=y, CONFIG_IP_VS=y, CONFIG_IP_VS_NFCT=y, CONFIG_IP_VS_RR=y, CONFIG_EXT4_FS=y, CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL=y, CONFIG_EXT4_FS_SECURITY=y

P.S. - Some of the above defconfigs may not be necessary to get the docker running. However, enabling all of them ensures you have extended support for all the features that docker offers.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, your system is missing a number of networking related kernel modules, from the look of it, it's looking for at least: bridge, br_netfilter, nf_nat, xt_conntrack. You'll need to port these missing kernel modules or recompile the kernel to include the relevant modules.

Comment: In my kernel defconfig, i have already enabled the following: CONFIG_NF_NAT=y, CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=y, CONFIG_BRIDGE=y, CONFIG_NETFILTER=y. This should probabily take care of the missing modules, right? But, still, the error persists. Please specify defconfigs,  if any, required additionaly to overcome the bug :)

Comment: @GauravMishra: does the warning messages still exist after you compile in those modules or is it just the error message now?

Comment: `@LieRyan` the warning messages remain intact. However, the error now looks something like this -`Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: Failed to program NAT chain: Failed to inject DOCKER in PREROUTING chain: iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1)`

Comment: If you want to remove the warnings, you might want to try building them as loadable kernel module instead of static modules. They're just warnings though, so I think they should be fine if you have the modules built in. Do you have the iptables and netfilters configs enabled in your kernel config?

Comment: `@LieRyan` Enabling appropriate configs helped me fix the bug. I forgot to enable a few earlier, but now it works. Thanks for your help.
However, even now my job is not done as when I try to run `docker pull` or `docker login` commands, I get the following error: `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 8.8.8.8:53: dial udp 8.8.8.8:53: connect: permission denied` . Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: On normal docker configuration, the docker daemon must run as root, while the docker client must run as a user that can connect to the docker socket (or root). Do you have both requirements satisfied?

Comment: `@Lie Ryan` Yes, i have both the requirements satisfied. I added my other user to the docker group as well. But that didn't help. I edited the nameserver earlier in /etc/resolve.conf file. When i use 8.8.8.8 nameserver i get `connect: permission denied` error and when i use 127.0.0.1 nameserver i get  `server misbehaving` error.

Comment: @GauravMishra who's the owner and group and permissions of the docker socket file? Were you able to run any docker commands that doesn't require the daemon to go to the network? For example, docker import an image from a tar file? What I'm trying to isolate here is whether the connection failure is for the client connecting to daemon vs the daemon connecting to the dockerhub.

Comment: `@Lie Ryan` Problem is for daemon connecting to the dockerhub. Client is able to connect to the daemon. However, even building images locally using tar files is causing error : `Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint objective_lamarr on network bridge: failed to add the host (vethc24f81f) <=> sandbox (veth1299fa2) pair interfaces: operation not supported.`

Comment: `@Lie Ryan` A big thank you. In the end, it was all all about compiling the kernel to include all the relevant modules. I was missing some or the other at every step. But, in the end, i was able to resolve the issue. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it all worked for you, it would probably make for an interesting read if you answered your own question or write a blog post to document all the relevant stuffs/module you had needed to do/enable in the kernel. It'll probably be useful for someone else too.

Comment: `@ Lie Ryan` Done :)